# Preserve ordering when consolidating two lists into a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, mysql-python

I am using mysqldb to connect to mysql database and I get the metadata/columns in a variable and data/row in another.  Now I have to consolidate the list and tuple into a dict and also preserve the order.  I know that dicts are orderless but is there any alternative to this?

```
cursor.description = ['userid', 'cid', 'mid', 'did', 'msid']
data = (29L, 35L, None, '', None)

result = {}
for i in data:
    result.update = dict(zip(cols, i))
```

Expected result

```
result = {'userid': 29L, 'cid': 35L, 'mid': None, 'did': '', 'msid': None}
```

Comment: "I know that dicts are orderless..." What problem are you hoping to solve by creating the `dict`?

Comment: Note that you can get `dict`s with a custom `Cursor`: http://geert.vanderkelen.org/fetching-rows-as-dictionaries-with-mysql-connectorpython/. You can combine that with `OrderedDict` to get ordered dictionaries from `.fetch` operations and cursor iteration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use an [*`OrderedDict`*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

result = OrderedDict(zip(cursor.description, data))
```

Example:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> cols = ['userid', 'cid', 'mid', 'did', 'msid']
>>> data = (29L, 35L, None, '', None)
>>> result = OrderedDict(zip(cols, data))
>>> result
OrderedDict([('userid', 29L), ('cid', 35L), ('mid', None), ('did', ''), ('msid', None)])
>>> result['userid']
29L
>>> result['cid']
35L
>>> list(result)
['userid', 'cid', 'mid', 'did', 'msid']
```

From CPython 3.6 onwards, and Python 3.7 onwards, regular `dict`s are sorted by insertion order, so you can use `dict` here instead of `OrderedDict` if you know your code will run under a suitable version.

Python 3.7+ only (or Python 3.6 under CPython):

```py
>>> cols = ['userid', 'cid', 'mid', 'did', 'msid']
>>> data = (29, 35, None, '', None)
>>> result = dict(zip(cols, data))
>>> result
{'userid': 29, 'cid': 35, 'mid': None, 'did': '', 'msid': None}
>>> result['userid']
29
>>> result['cid']
35
>>> list(result)
['userid', 'cid', 'mid', 'did', 'msid']
```

Comment: For versions of Python older than 2.7, you'll need to install it. `pip install ordereddict`

Comment: how can I make a dictionary of the result?
`[[('userid', 32L), ('cid', 40L), ('mid', None), ('did', ''), ('msid', None)]]`

Comment: `result` *is* a dictionary (`OrderedDict` is a subclass of `dict`). It is also ordered, unlike plain `dict`. For example, you can access `result['userid']` and basically treat it like a `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

forget the dict

```
>>> cols=['userid', 'cid', 'mid', 'did', 'msid']
>>> data = (29L, 35L, None, '', None)
>>> zip(cols,data)
[('userid', 29L), ('cid', 35L), ('mid', None), ('did', ''), ('msid', None)]
```

If you have lots of result sets then set up an array first and `append` to it

```
>>> myarray.append(zip(cols,data))
```

Comment: Good, but it makes looking for a specific column cumbersome. Maybe I just want to write `row['userid']`.