# df.rename does not alter df column names, but df.columns and df.set_axis do (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to rename the columns on

When I run:

```
df.rename(columns={0:"C", 1:"D"}, inplace=True)
```

No change happens, it's still the original column names.
But if I do:

```
df.columns = ["C", "D"]
```

or

```
df.set_axis(["C", "D"],axis=1, inplace=True)
```

It works.

Why does not `df.rename` work?

NOTE: I specifically would like to rename the first and second column regardless of what their name is, it may change (in my case) so I can't specify it.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": pd.Series(range(0,2)),"B": pd.Series(range(2,4))})
df
    A   B
1   0   2
2   1   3

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": pd.Series(range(0,2)),"B": pd.Series(range(2,4))})
df.rename(columns={0:"C", 1:"D"}, inplace=True)
df
    A   B
1   0   2
2   1   3

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": pd.Series(range(0,2)),"B": pd.Series(range(2,4))})
df.columns = ["C", "D"]
df
    C   D
0   0   2
1   1   3

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": pd.Series(range(0,2)),"B": pd.Series(range(2,4))})
df.set_axis(["C", "D"],axis=1, inplace=True)
df
    C   D
0   0   2
1   1   3
```

EDIT:

My original dataframe had the column names `0` and `1` which is why `df.rename(columns={0:"C", 1:"D"}, inplace=True)` worked.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([range(2,4), range(4,6)])
df
    0   1
0   2   3
1   4   5

df.rename(columns={0:"C", 1:"D"}, inplace=True)
df
    C   D
0   2   3
1   4   5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Renaming column names in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-column-names-in-pandas)

Comment: `df.rename(columns={0:"C", 1:"D"}, inplace=True)` to `df.rename(columns={'A':"C", 'B':"D"}, inplace=True)`

Comment: Thank you @AshkanGolehPour, but that does not solve my problem because I'm working with many dataframes and the first column is not always named `A`, but I do know that the first column should be re-named to `C`

Comment: Thank you @Kins, but no. I read it and I cannot see that it helps my case of renaming column names by integer position and not name (E.G. renaming the first column to `C` with specifying the name of the first column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to rename by using the old name, you could `zip` the current columns and pass in the number of items you want.

If you're using Python 3.7+ then order should be [preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372949/preserve-ordering-when-consolidating-two-lists-into-a-dict)

Also don't use [`inplace=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true-in-pandas)

```
print(df)

   A  B
0  0  2
1  1  3
```

---

```
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, ['C','E'])))

   C  E
0  0  2
1  1  3
```

---

```
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, ['E'])))

   E  B
0  0  2
1  1  3
```

Comment: Nice use of `zip`. Note that you can generalize to any column position with `dict(zip(df.iloc[:, [3,7]].columns, ['C','E']))` (for columns 3, 7). (+1)

Comment: `df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, ['C','E'])), inplace=True)` work, but then I would, personally, prefer `df.columns = ["C", "D"]` however my question is still unanswered. Is it possible to use `df.rename` to change the name of column number `X` to `new_name`

Comment: @mozway the generalized expression `df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.iloc[:, [0,1]].columns, ['C','D'])), inplace=True)` woks nice.